# Apache Oozie as a business workflow engine

Tags: workflow, oozie

I am new to Apache Oozie and have so far understood that it can be used to create and manage workflows for hadoop jobs. But can it be also used to serve as a business workflow engine (like JBPM)? I was trying to search for any resources which points to this, but was unable to locate any. Can you please help pointing me to a few resources which talks about this?

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: What do you expect from a business worfklow engine? Oozie can run arbitrary programs, it depends on what features you need.